# Restrict google map autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to restrict google to only 'address', '(cities)', '(regions)' et remove commercial market name.
According to the documentation

> types
>   Type:  Array
>   The types of predictions to be returned. Four types are supported: >'establishment' for businesses, 'geocode' for addresses, '(regions)' for >administrative regions and '(cities)' for localities. If nothing is specified, >all types are returned.

But this code return nothing

```
var options = {
    types: ['address', '(cities)', '(regions)']
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7pa4x12L/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're suppose to specify only one type. As [Add Autocomplete for places and addresses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) says:

> In general only a single type is allowed.The exception is that you can
>   safely mix the geocode and establishment types, but note that this
>   will have the same effect as specifying no types

That's why if you check the sample code from [Restrict the search to a specific country](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#placeholder_text) you can see that there's only one type specified.

```
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};
```

You can see more of this in the [Autocomplete sample demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).